# Filter Django QuerySet to include the results from the given list only

Tags: django

I need to get all books which title contain all 'parts' from the variable-length list.

Like (not working):

```
title_list = ['tree', 'sun']
books = Books.objects.filter(title__icontains=title_list)
```

or in SQL (working):

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE title LIKE '%tree%' AND title LIKE '%sun%';
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
from django.db.models import Q

title_list = ['tree', 'sun']

Books.objects.filter(reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, [Q(title__icontains=title) for title in title_list]))
```

Comment: Note, you'd need to make sure `title_list` isn't empty first, otherwise this will raise a `TypeError` from `reduce`. It does work if `title_list` contains 1 or more though.

Comment: Thanks! It's quite interesting way, I could not imagine a reduce() here.

Comment: Yeah, you could certainly loop through it to create the `Q` object, but I wanted to figure out a one-liner.